# How to I redirect a function call and then callback to the "original" function c++

Tags: c++, hook

I have a situation where I can not modify code, it is compiled and I can not modify the source, but need to log some data that is being sent to it. I can link to it via DLL. I am trying to capture the function call, redirect it to a new DLL that is linked in, store the data I need, but then call the unmodified function. I can capture the call by just doing a dllimport and redefining the function in my DLL, but then at the end I can't call the original function. Since they are the same name, it is just becoming a recursive call. How do I callback and exit?

I am using VC++ under VS2005.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [EasyHook](http://easyhook.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use DllImport to load the original function.

Instead use LoadLibrary(Ex) and GetProcAddress to load the original DLL and find the original function and put it in a variable.  Once that is done you can call the original function via the variable.

Comment: When I load the dll, I get a valid handle, but when I call GetProcAddress, it returns null. I even tried it on my own compiled DLL, and I get the same. That function seems so easy to use, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Did you export the function(s) from your DLL?